# Volumes in the host system

Tags: docker

I can create a docker volume using a relative path:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
    volumes:
      - ./dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
```

Then, `dbdata` will be available on my `WSL 2`, and I will be able to enter it (with sudo su) and inspect its contents.

Yet, when I run `docker volume ls`, I see only json below, which does not look like my dbdata volume at all:

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2020-11-03T09:19:37Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/5d668164c5bcdf4cc01e4c8fbc20cc1155f757d4ba06dc5118fa2d0a0b5efb9b/_data",
        "Name": "5d668164c5bcdf4cc01e4c8fbc20cc1155f757d4ba06dc5118fa2d0a0b5efb9b",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

But [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/) I found this quote.

> When you create a volume, it is stored within a directory on the Docker host

So my docker volumes should not be on my WSL 2 filesystem at all, they should reside on the [Docker host instead](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/#docker-architecture). Then why do I see my volumes inside WSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, the quote you referenced applies to **named** volumes. That is, the volumes created either by `docker volume create` command or volumes defined in docker-compose.yml in the root `volumes` section, but not in volumes section inside a specific service.

More specifically, that syntax creates a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) and not a named volume.

Comment: More specifically, that syntax creates a _bind mount_ and not a named volume.